# In JMeter, how to allow multiple threads to upload files concurrently

Tags: jmeter

I have written a simple test plan with the following steps

## Test Plan

1. View Results in Table
2. Aggregate Report

#### Thread group

- Threads: 5
- Ramp-up period: 0s
- Loop count: 1

#### Inside Thread Group

1. A dummy sampler to prove that all threads are running concurrently
2. HTTP request to upload a file

When I run the above tests, the dummy sampler is executed nearly the same time. However, I realize that only 1 thread can execute the HTTP request to upload file at a time, even when I have multiple threads. So the final result will be Thread 1 upload file -> finish -> Thread 2 upload file ... e.t.c.

Is this a normal behaviour and can I make file upload performs concurrently from multiple threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of threads, loop count and ramp-up period. JMeter starts threads within the time frame you specify in "Ramp-up period" input and the threads start executing [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). When there are no samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread is being shut down.

If you need to configure JMeter to execute a certain request **at exactly the same time** by several threads add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of this request and configure "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" setting to match the number of simultaneous users

[image: JMeter Synchroinizing Timer]

Example execution:

[image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer Example]

As you can see, `Dummy Samplers` were started in 2 seconds while `HTTP Request` samplers were executed at nearly the same moment.

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) article for more information on implementing these "rendezvous points" in JMeter tests